# How Stackoverflow has implemented the logic for displaying flags on mouse over of comments

Tags: asp.net

I need logic to display images on mouse over of datagrid in asp.net

Comment: Right mouse button -> View Source

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how SO does it do as Wikser suggests and view the source.  If you want help to do something similar then I'll need to know what client side libraries yo are using.

Without having looked at SO source I see an empty space that an image appears in when the mouse is over something else.  If I were to recreate this behavior I would do something like this for the HTML:

```
<img src="..." id="flag" style="visibility: hidden"/>
...
<span id="comment">blah blah blah</span>
```

and I would use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) like this to set up the effect:

```
$("#comment").hover(
    function() {$("#flag").css("visibility", "visible"},
    function() {$("#flag").css("visibility", "hidden"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest try jQuery balloon tips

Here are many examples.

http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/05/12-jquery-tooltip-for-web-developer.html

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/announcing-beautytips-jquery-tooltip-plugin

The logic is that create on fly a cool div set with your informations, and display it on mouse over, in the position you wish.